# Bigquery, counts distinct of all columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in bigquery that has arouns 500 columns. I want to get a distinct count of all columns. It's not optimal to do count(distinct col1) individually. Can anyone recommend a more optimal way to do so? I am looking to return a table with two columns. Column one should have the column names, and column 2 should have the count distinct value.
Thank you!

I tried to use information_schema.columns to return all columns. However, I wasn't sure what to do next.